# REST: Validate or check permissions first for request when permission depends on request data?

Tags: rest, api, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-400

I'm writing a REST API that has a file resouce `/files` and permissions to grant other users access to the files `/files/{id}/permissions`.

The API is only used internally so there is no authorization, but all of the requests still require a `userId` to indicate on behalf of which user the request should be performed.

A request for creating a new file may look like:

```
POST /files

{
  "userId": 1,
  "name": "Example",
  "content": "Example content"
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "ownerUserId": 1,
  "name": "Example",
  "content": "Example content"
}
```

I've been under the impression that one should first check if the user is permitted to perform the requested action and then validate if the request (I've been following this [HTTP decision diagram](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/for-GET/http-decision-diagram/master/httpdd.png); `is_forbidden` before `is_request_block_ok`), but that seems a bit counter intuitive for a create permission request:

```
POST /files/1/permissions

{
  "userId": -1, // Intentionally invalid value
  "granteeId": 5,
  "role": "READER"
}
```

I would expect this to return a `400 Bad Request` due to `userId = -1`, but I get a `403 Forbidden`, because I check permission (the user attempting to create the permission should be the owner of the file) before validating the request.

Should the order of check permission and validate request be reversed or am I doing it in the correct order?

If my order of execution is correct what would the expected response to the above invalid request be (400 or 403)?

Comment: Probably `400` is not the most suitable status code assuming that the JSON is _syntactically_ valid. I would consider using `422` to indicate that the JSON is _semantically_ invalid.

Comment: That's a completely different discussion though :-)